# Comparing data to table in the database

Tags: php, mysql, database, excel, csv

I receive raw data in CSVs, and upload it to a table in a MySQL database (upon which my website functions).  I want to compare a newer CSV to the data I uploaded from an older CSV, and I want to see the differences between the two (basically I want to diff the raw data with the table).

I have PHP, MySQL, and my desktop apps (e.g. Excel) at my disposal. What's the best way to go about this?  Possible ways I can think of:

- Inserting the newer data into a
  Table_Copy, then somehow diffing the
  two tables in mysql.
- Somehow querying the database in 
  comparison to the rawdata without
  having to upload it.
- Downloading the data from the
  database into raw CSV format, and
  then comparing the two raw CSV's using a desktop program

Answer (score 1):

Why don't you use the where clause to pull only the data that is new?  For instance

```
select * from table where dateadded > '1-1-2011 18:18'
```

This depends on your table having a dateadded column and populating that with the date and time the data is added.

Comment: I do have an Added_DateTime column so this is an option

Comment: One problem with this method is there's no way to know about rows which have been *removed*

Answer (score 0):

```
diff <(mysqldump test old_csv --skip-extended-insert) <(mysqldump test new_csv --skip-extended-insert) --side-by-side --suppress-common-lines --width=690 | more
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following approaches

1) Database Table comparison - create a copy of the table and then compare data.

You can use propriety tools to do it easily (Eg : [EMS Data comparer](http://www.sqlmanager.net/products/mysql/datacomparer)).

You can also write some simple queries to achieve this (Eg : select id from table_copy not in (select id in table) )

2) Use a file comparer like [winmerge](http://winmerge.org/)
   Take the dump of both the tables with exact method, and them compare it.

I use both the approaches depending on my data size.  For smaller data 2nd approach is good.